# c# polymorphism + generics design - advice needed

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have a hierarchy of `TrendProviders` which are used to provide a series of datapoints (trends) from different sources.

I have started with the generic interface:

```
public interface ITrendProvider<T> where T: TrendResult
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetTrends(); 
}
```

`TrendResult` is a result class with the obtained trend data and operation status code:

```
public class TrendResult
{
    public TrendResult()
    {
        Points = new Dictionary<DateTimeOffset, decimal>();
    }

    public TrendResultCode Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DateTimeOffset, decimal> Points { get; set; }
}
```

`TrendResultCode` is as follows:

```
public enum TrendResultCode
{
    OK,
    DataParseError,
    NoData,
    UnknownError
}
```

There are also two types (so far) of more detailed interfaces:

- `IFileTrendProvider` - used to obtain trends from any files.
- `IServerTrendProvider` - used to obtain trends from remote servers, using FTP for example.

`IFileTrendProvider` goes like this:

```
public interface IFileTrendProvider : ITrendProvider<TrendResult>
{
    IFileReader FileReader {get; set}
    FileTrendDiscoveryPattern Pattern {get; set;}  
}
```

`IServerTrendProvider` goes like this:

```
public interface IServerTrendProvider : ITrendProvider<TrendResult>
{
    IClient Client { get; set; }
    Dictionary<string, string[]> RequestedServerTrendIDs { get; set; }
}
```

The concrete classes that implements the interfaces are as follows:

One of `FileTrend` type:

```
public class GenericFileTrendProvider : IFileTrendProvider<TrendResult>
{
    public GenericFileTrendProvider() { }

    public IFileReader FileReader {get; set}
    public FileTrendDiscoveryPattern Pattern {get; set;}  

    public IEnumerable<TrendResult> GetTrends()
    {
       // Some code to obtain trends from file using FileReader
    }
}
```

And one of the `ServerTrend` type:

```
public class ServerATrendProvider : IServerTrendProvider<TrendResult>
{
    public ServerATrendProvider () { }

    public IClient Client { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> RequestedServerTrendIDs { get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<TrendResult> GetTrends()
    {
       // Some code to obtain trends from remote server using Client
    }
}
```

Now, what I want to achieve and where I need your help and advice:

The `IFileReader` introduces its own error codes:

```
public enum FileReadResultCode
{
    OK,
    FileAlreadyOpen,
    FileNotFound,
    UnknownError
}
```

`IClient` also introduces its specific operation error codes:

```
public enum ClientCode
{
    OK,
    InvalidCredentials,
    ResourceNotFounds,
    UnknownError
}
```

As both: `IFileReader` and `IClient` also returns its own error codes, how could I intruduce them in the `TrendResult` object returned by `GetTrends()` method, so that in the end there will be also some information about the "internal" error, not only `TrendResult` specific error?

I would need some flexible solution - I was thinking about inheriting from `TrendResult` and create a `FileTrendResult` and `ServerTrendResult` for each of concrete providers, and also define a specific error enumerations for both so that they return its own result type, but can it be done in some other way?

Comment: Great question pitersmx. Normally we don't add any greetings or thanks you's to the post to make sure there's as little noise in the post as possible. I've edited your thanks out for you, just that you know.

Comment: Now I need some great answer :)

Comment: Do the specific results apply to a single `TrendResult` or are they the same for all trend results that are read from a source (e.g. file). For instance, does the `GenericFileTrendProvider` read several files at once so that some of the returned `TrendResults` could have the code `FileNotFound` whereas others would have `Ok` or some other code?

Comment: @Markus Inside the `GetTrends()` method I use `yield` to return one `TrendResult` at a time, which then is processed and stored in a database. So for EVERY trend that is supposed to be read either from a file or from the server, one `TrendResult` should be returned, with the exact detailed information about error related to this single trend - if there is any error, I have to push it to the Logger.

Comment: Continuation: I just need some convenient way to pass the exact information about the error - why the trend could not been retrieved. Of cource, for situation where I have let's say 10 trends to read from one file which is currently opened by somebody else, I will get 10x TrendResult with `FileAlreadyOpen` code - that is wanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having a pre-defined list of possible errors in the enumerations (`TrendResultCode`, `FileReadResultCode`, `ClientCode`, ...) you could change the `TrendResult` class to store a list of exceptions and get rid of the enumerations:

```
public class TrendResult
{
    // ...    
    // public TrendResultCode Code { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Exception> Errors { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

This way, you can store the complete information of the error including stack trace and other valuable information (or of several errors if there is more than one problem in a single `TrendResult`). Even for unexpected errors, you are able to store the details instead of having an unknown error that is hard to track down.

If a  `TrendResult` does not have any items in the enumeration, there are no problems with it. Otherwise, you can put the information to the log.

The implementation follows the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), so you don't have to change the implementation that handles the `TrendResults` if there are new conditions that lead to an error.

For your business exceptions, e.g. parsing errors, you should create specific exception types so that you are able to analyze these errors later on based on their type.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I am starting to like your solution a lot.
I think that this is the right way for me to go. Once again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since IServerTrendProvider will be receiving TrendResults from other computers, you will not be able to use [System.Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) in the general case.

In these cirumstances, people fall back to strings - which are always supported regardless of operating system.

```
public class TrendResult
{
   public string[] ErrorMessages;  // Error messages - could be the stack trace
   public int[]    ErrorCodes;     // Os-specific error numbers
}
```

Consider security when sending source-code fragments (e.g. names, stack traces) in error messages, because these could be of use to hackers.